# Jasper reports and report parameters

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I have a jasper report with a field $F{fupgrade_package_name}

so when I run my query upgrade_package_name is set to http://www.something.com/file.exe

I want to only display file.exe in the report and not the full URL.

How is this done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this expression:

```
<parameter name="url" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["http://www.something.com/file.exe"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>

<textField>
    <reportElement x="122" y="28" width="100" height="20"/>
    <textElement/>
    <textFieldExpression>
        <![CDATA[$P{url}.contains("/") ? $P{url}.split("/")[$P{url}.split("/").length-1] : $P{url}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

The result will be:

> file.exe

And for the **`url = "just_file_wout_url.txt"`** the result will be:

> just_file_wout_url.txt

For your case the expression will be:

```
$F{fupgrade_package_name}.contains("/") ? $F{fupgrade_package_name}.split("/")[$F{fupgrade_package_name}.split("/").length-1] : $F{fupgrade_package_name}
```

Comment: but, in your answer, "url" has to be a field, it is one per row of data from the query. Does it not have to be a parameter?

Comment: @reza It is no matter - it is just a sample. You can change it to the field - `$F{url}`. But the expression is right

Comment: For your case the expression will be: `$F{fupgrade_package_name}.contains("/") ? $F{fupgrade_package_name}.split("/")[$F{fupgrade_package_name}.split("/").length-1] : $F{fupgrade_package_name}`

Comment: Ohh, I forgot - the report language must be `Java`. Yes sure, it is works for me. The `Groovy` works also

Answer (score 0):

you can handle the `$F{fupgrade_package_name}.split(regex)[0]` like a String, you would use a regular expression.